# Why is this write() to standard output not working?

Tags: c

Why is the line `write(1, lol, 1);` not working in the `main` function? It just blank and returned value 0 for end of program, but when I call function `filecopy(0,1)`, it works?

EDIT: I included `"syscall.h"`

```
int main(void)
{
    ///// filecopy(0,1)
    char lol = 'D';
    write(1, lol, 1);
    return 0;
}

void filecopy(int from, int to)
{
  int n;
  int buf[100];

  while((n=read(from, buf, 100)) > 0)
    write(to, buf, n);
}
```

Comment: Turn on your compiler's warnings and fix the issues reported.

Comment: The POSIX functions `read()` and `write()` are declared in `<unistd.h>`.  You should seldom if ever need `"syscall.h"` — I've used it once in my career, and that was for accessing a system call where the manual says "there is no function for this system call".

Comment: Note that you have the wrong type for `n` - it should be `size_t` (or `ssize_t`), not `int`. Also the size passed to `read` should be `100 * sizeof(int)`, not `100` (either that or make the type of `buff` `char` rather than `int`).

Comment: @PaulR: As long as `sizeof(int)` is not bigger than 4, it will 'work' OK, but it is aconventional to use just a quarter of the buffer, and to use an array of `int` as if it were an array of `char`.  And `int` for `n` is OK when the sizes are small as they are here.  `size_t` for `n` could be a fiasco if the `write()` failed and returned `-1`; EOF would be detected with `0` which is OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `filecopy()` function, you got the call to `write()` right.

```
write(to, buf, n);    //buf is a pointer.
```

In your `main()`code, the problem is in the line

```
write(1, lol, 1);      // lol is of type char, it's not an address.
```

The second argument to [`write()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/write) should be a `void *`. Change to

```
  write(1, &lol, 1);
```

It's highly recommended to enable the warnings in your compiler and take a look and fix the warnings emitted by your compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Write takes an address -- NOT a value (http://linux.die.net/man/2/write). The correct way to invoke write is

```
int main(void)
{
    ///// filecopy(0,1)
    char lol = 'D';
    write(1, &lol, 1);
    return 0;
}
```